If G/K is quasicyclic can we say that G doesn't have proper subgroups of finite index
If G/K is quasicyclic and G is abelian (i don't know if it's needed but in this case i know G is abelian) can we say that G doesn't have proper subgroups of finite index (that i guess equals to G being divisible)?
If G has a proper subgroup H of finite index it has to be G = HK in addition G = $\bigcup_nA_nK$ with$A_n$ cyclic, $A_nK < A_{n+1}K$ and $A_nK< G$ for each n (strict inclusion this last one) so if i could say that $H\subseteq A_nK$ for some n then i'll have a contradiction and the statement would be true. But i'm not  sure if i can say that
